# How to count the occurrence of a specific character in a string

Tags: f#

I'm not sure where to begin with the checking of a string for n occurrences of a specific char. I've laid out the basic outline of what I assume to be the framework for the function but the contents I'm not sure about?

```
let countCharFromNth (getStr : string)(chkdChar : char) = 
    if getStr.Length >=1 then 

    else printfn "Not enough arguments"
```

Comment: `Seq.filter ((=) chkdChar) >> Seq.length`

Comment: In general, [avoid asking for external resources](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ("Also any recommendations for F# reading material? Thanks.") For starters, check the 'canonical' [fsharpforfunandprofit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tail recursive loop version.

```
let countCharFromNth (getStr : string)(chkdChar : char) = 
    let rec loop i count =
        if i < getStr.Length then 
            if getStr.[i] = chkdChar then loop (i+1) (count+1)
            else loop (i+1) count
        else count
    loop 0 0
```

It will get translated into an imperative loop by the compiler as all function calls are in the tail (last) position. While longer than the other versions, this is the most performant way of doing it as it does not create unnecessary intermediate collections.

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR**

The 'most idiomatic' way is probably @Mark Seemanns:

```
let count x = Seq.filter ((=) x) >> Seq.length
```

*The **T**oo**L**ong part*

Note that this function is fully generic: `x:'a -> (seq<'a> -> int) when 'a : equality`, i.e. it counts occurrences of any `x` in a sequence of `'a`s, as long as `'a` supports equality. Due to the right-hand side being a function, we also don't need to specify the string argument. This is called [point-free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) style.
The function is constructed by turning the `=` operator into a function by wrapping it in parentheses (think `(=)` = `fun x y -> x = y`), filtering the sequence with this predicate and calculating the resulting `seq`s length, i.e.

```
let count x xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.filter (fun x' -> x' = x)
    |> Seq.length
```

which is

```
let count x xs =
    Seq.length(Seq.filter (fun x' -> x' = x) xs)
```

Of course you can also leverage 'the C# way':

```
let count' x xs = System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(xs, fun x' -> x' = x)
```

Here you can't just turn the equality operator `(=)` into a predicate because the F# compiler needs to do some magic to turn the F# `'a -> bool` into a `Func<'a, bool>`.

The usage is exactly the same:

```
count 'a' "abbbac"
```

or (more readable)

```
"abbbac" |> count 'a'
"abbac" |> count' 'b'
```

This (and better composability) is the reason functional programmers tend to reverse the order of arguments (`count x xs` vs. `count xs x`).

More exotic (and less performant) solutions:

```
let count'' (c : char) str =
    (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, string c)).Count

let count''' (c : char) str =
    (String.length str) - (str.Replace(string c, "") |> String.length)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using fold is another option:

```
open System

let countCharFold targetChar = 
  Seq.fold (fun count ch -> if ch = targetChar then count + 1 else count) 0

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let text = "hello world"
  let ch = 'l'
  printfn "%d" (countCharFold ch text)

  Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  0
```

Answer (score 0):

To give another, possibly more functionally oriented solution, I tried changing the suggested answer into a pattern matching inner loop:

```ml
let charCountFrom str i chr = 
    let rec loop = function
        | (it, count) when (String.length str) = it -> count
        | (it, count) when str.[it] = chr -> loop (it+1, count+1)
        | (it, count) -> loop (it+1, count)
    loop (i,0)
```

I use pattern matching with when cases to essentially emulate the if/else structures, with a shortcut to end the loop when the iterator goes out of bounds.

This version also allows to specify `i` being the starting index for counting, but it can easily be removed by replacing occurrences of `i` with 0.

Reordering of arguments also allows for currying, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem recently and settled on:

```
let countCharInStr (chr: char) =
  Seq.sumBy (fun chr' -> if chr = chr' then 1 else 0)
```