# How to delete a part of a string in a cell after a second occurence of a specific character?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a name of a person in one cell in the following format:

> Surname, Name, Department

I would like to go through an entire column of those names and trim off everything **after the second comma "," only**. Could you please suggest how this could be done? I found similar topics, but have no idea how to get this done with many occurrences of the same character:

[delete data in cell after specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957975/delete-data-in-cell-after-specific-character)

I guess the structure would implement something as such, however I have no idea how to do it in VBA:

[How to count the occurrence of a specific character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022846/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-a-specific-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Even simpler!

Answer (score 1):

A simple formula will do it:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","}}}",2))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Scott, thank you! Simple and elegant. Would you be so kind please and teach me how this could be looped through the entire column of names?

Comment: @B.Malysz just copy the formula down the column it will adjust the references automatically.

Comment: It will feed trimmed names from one table to another in separate spreadsheets (5-12k names), could this be automated within a click of a button, please?

Comment: Sure, but SO is not a code for me site. break your steps down and use google to find how to do each step in vba.  when you get stuck come back with your code and explain exactly the error and ask a specific question regarding that error and we will help overcome that specific error.